# How to bring iframe to front

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a problem with an iframe on a page surrounded by a header and footer.

There is a div in the header which overlaps the iframe ( in blue below ).
[image]

The div with id logo looks like this:

```
 #logo {
      z-index: 9998;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 0px;
  }
```

The white part of the page is an iframe.

```
 <iframe src="somepage" scrolling="auto" class="study-iframe" style="height:700px;"></iframe>
```

The words "What does a course attribute mean?" are a link.

```
     <div id="Attr1View1">
         <p>
         <a href="javascript:Toggle2Views('Attr1View2', 'Attr1View1')">
         <font class="LinkNoUnderline">+ </font>
         <font class="LinkNoUnderlineText">What does a course attribute mean?</font>
         </a>
         </p>
     </div>
```

When I click on an area which is covered by the blue rectangle, nothing happens.

when I click on an area outside the blue rectangle, the link works.

How can I force the links on this page to the front, so that you can always click on them ?

Thanks

Comment: Answer: don't use absolute positioning for layouts.

Comment: set z-index of iframe higher than that of logo

Comment: It's not a link issue, like Diodeus said, it's a layout issue due to absolute positioning, either way the simplest solution from the top of my head would be to set a fixed height on the blue div equal to the header height. Please comment if it doesn't work, i'll turn it into a fiddle and see if i can find a fix there.

Comment: @Hazard, thanks.  I forced the height to be shorter and problem solved.  It's the best solution for me because I have no control over the iframe content, and the header div makes sense on every other webpage on the website.

Answer (score 3):

**Layout**
With the Layout Make sure that you do not use Positions as it will make the web page disorientated on other browsers and screen resolutions.

**IFrame**
If you are gonna keep your Layout using Positions then an easy way to do it will be to...

```
iframe{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Please restrain from Positioning your layout.

Comment: With some systems it is necessary to use positioning. This should be worked around; your second solution is good but reconsider the first.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Why yes you are so right, but I have only submitted 1 solution and that was dedicated to his original code, However the second solution was a recommendation.

Comment: Additionally, I think that he/she used absolute positioning so that elements can be next to eachother but a more dynamic approach is to have a wrapper of 1024px or smaller and put the elements inside to have either Float: left; or Display: Inline-block; :)

Comment: The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) outlines principles for answering. Generally you are advised not to try to change the code but to work with and around what's there. Thus, your first ("**Layout**") section contradicts this, but your second section provides a much more useful answer: it outlines how the current code can be made to work.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean :P It was all one answer, the **Layout** was just a recommendation, Sorry about Posting my Email, I was only trying to give out 1 to 1 advice :)